# Javascript/jquery- How to get time closest within an array?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I'm trying to get the closest time in an array or list ect. 
I was able to locate this code and have tried to get it to work by making edits but without any luck.
Can use jquery if it makes it easier. below is only javascript though
How can I output the time closest to the time which = thetime

After more research I have found this snippet and think it may be useful for my cause:

```
var date1 = myDate,
date2 = new Date();
return (date1.getTime() < date2.getTime());
```

What I'm trying

```
var currentTime = new Date()
var hours = currentTime.getHours()
var minutes = currentTime.getMinutes()

if (minutes < 10) {
    minutes = "0" + minutes
}

var thetime = hours + ":" + minutes + " "

var json = [{
    "times": {
        "times1": "20:01",
        "times2": "21:43",
        "times3": "22:56",
        "times4": "23:21"
    }
}]
var times = [];
var jsontimes = json[0].times;
for (var i in jsontimes) {
    times.push(new Date(jsontimes[i]))
}
times.sort(function (a, b) {
    return Math.abs(thetime - a / new Date()) + Math.abs(thetime - b / new Date())
});

// display code
for (var i = 0; i < jsontimes.length; i++)
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML += dates[i] + "<br>";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to create Date objects with invalid values (e.g., "20:01"), resulting in invalid dates. According to MDN, you can pass parameters in the following ways when creating a new Date object:

```
Date(value)
Date(dateString)
Date(year, month, day [, hour, minute, second, millisecond])
```

where
value is an "integer value representing the number of milliseconds since 1 January 1970 00:00:00 UTC (Unix Epoch)." and

dateString is a "string value representing a date. The string should be in a format recognized by the parse method (IETF-compliant RFC 2822 timestamps)."

You can read more here: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

This doesn't really answer your initial question, but it should help you create an array with the values you want.